# Arduino use the last serial command input until the next one is recieved

Tags: python, user-interface, input, arduino

I have build a Python-Arduino system that communicate thru serial. The Python script sends every 2 seconds a instruction, as a string, to the Arduino. The python has a second delay before sending the next command. The problem is that the Arduino in this 1 second delay stop working, as it does not remember the last given command. I want to store the last received string and use it until another one comes.

Thank you!

---

```
char datafromUser=0;
int VCC_Control = 2;

int pompa_bacuri = 30;
int stop_pompa_bacuri = 31;

int pompa_avans = 32;
int stop_pompa_avans = 33;

int pompa_unghi = 32;
int stop_pompa_unghi = 33;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once,
  pinMode( VCC_Control , OUTPUT );
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(pompa_bacuri, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stop_pompa_bacuri, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pompa_avans, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stop_pompa_avans, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pompa_unghi, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stop_pompa_unghi, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(pompa_bacuri, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pompa_avans, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(stop_pompa_bacuri, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(stop_pompa_avans, HIGH);
  pinMode(pompa_unghi, HIGH);
  pinMode(stop_pompa_unghi, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  
  
  
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    datafromUser=Serial.read();
    Serial.println((char) datafromUser);

  }

    String sync = Serial.readString();

    while (Serial.available())
    {
        sync += Serial.read();
    }
    
    // Print debug
        
    // Split
    char  cut = sync.substring(0, 1)[0];   
    char  presa_R1= sync.substring(1, 2)[0];    
    char  presa_R2 = sync.substring(2, 3)[0];    
    char  bacuri_R1 = sync.substring(3, 4)[0];    
    char  bacuri_R2 = sync.substring(4, 5)[0];       
    char  unghi_R1 = sync.substring(5, 6)[0];
    char  unghi_R2 = sync.substring(6, 7)[0];
    char  viteza = sync.substring(7)[0];
    
    // Print debug
    Serial.print("Presa_releu_avans: ");
    Serial.println(presa_R1);
    Serial.print("Presa_releu_retragere: ");
    Serial.println(presa_R2);
    Serial.print("Bacuri_releu_avans: ");
    Serial.println(bacuri_R1);
    Serial.print("Bacuri_releu_retragere: ");
    Serial.println(bacuri_R2);
    Serial.print("Bacuri_releu_avans: ");
    Serial.println(unghi_R1);
    Serial.print("Bacuri_releu_retragere: ");
    Serial.println(unghi_R2);
    Serial.print("Viteza_de_avans_presa: ");
    Serial.println(viteza);
 
/////////////# CONTROL RELEE PRESA #/////////////

  //de vazut live cum se duc pistoanele 
  
  if(presa_R1 == '0') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_avans, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_avans, LOW);
    }

   if(presa_R1 == '1') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_bacuri, LOW);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_bacuri, HIGH);
    }


  if(presa_R2 == '0') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_avans, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_avans, LOW);
    }

   if(presa_R2 == '1') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_bacuri, LOW);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_bacuri, HIGH);
    }

/////////////# CONTROL RELEE PRESA #/////////////


/////////////# CONTROL RELEE PRESA #/////////////

  //de vazut live cum se duc pistoanele 
  
  if(bacuri_R1 == '0') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_bacuri, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_bacuri, LOW);
    }

   if(bacuri_R1 == '1') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_bacuri, LOW);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_bacuri, HIGH);
    }


  if(bacuri_R2 == '0') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_bacuri, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_bacuri, LOW);
    }

   if(bacuri_R2 == '1') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_bacuri, LOW);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_bacuri, HIGH);
    }

/////////////# CONTROL RELEE PRESA #/////////////



/////////////# CONTROL RELEE PRESA #/////////////

  //de vazut live cum se duc pistoanele 
  
  if(unghi_R1 == '0') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_unghi, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_unghi, LOW);
    }

   if(unghi_R1 == '1') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_unghi, LOW);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_unghi, HIGH);
    }


  if(unghi_R2 == '0') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_unghi, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_unghi, LOW);
    }

   if(unghi_R2 == '1') {
      Serial.println("POMPA BACURI PORNITA");
      digitalWrite(stop_pompa_unghi, LOW);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(pompa_unghi, HIGH);
    }

/////////////# CONTROL RELEE PRESA #/////////////



  
          if(viteza == 'a'){
              for (int i = 0; i<200000; i++){
                one();
              }
          }
        
           if(viteza == 'b'){
              for (int i = 0; i<200000; i++){
                two();
              }
          }
  
}


void one() {
    digitalWrite(VCC_Control, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(VCC_Control, LOW);
    delay(800);
    Serial.write((char) datafromUser);
}


void two() {
    digitalWrite(VCC_Control, HIGH);
    delay(800);
    digitalWrite(VCC_Control, LOW);
    delay(200);
    Serial.write((char) datafromUser);
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Put the

```html
String sync = Serial.readString();
```

line inside the

```html
if(Serial.available())
{

}
```

condition, like this:

```html
if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    datafromUser=Serial.read();
    Serial.println((char) datafromUser);
    String sync = Serial.readString();
  }
```

That way, your sync variable will remain the same unless there is indeed a new command sent from the Python.
Once your sync variable will remain the same, your previous command will keep occurring until a new command is received from the Python machine via serial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I run the code but it tells me that sync was not declared in this scope. If I run all the code inside the if function, so that the sync runs with no problem, the void one() and void two() are not called.

Comment: Declare String Sync; above the setup function. Then in the If Serial.Available() condition Just use Sync = Serial.ReadString();